# How to read a FB Page's stream from a webpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Solved - hmmm - well - I was overflowing a pipe, which seems to be what was causing the hang.

Also, the empty stream results sees to have been due to a page restriction of 17+ for the BBN FB page ... once set back to the 13+ setting (there really was no reason to restrict it), the stream shows up just fine.

Comment: Please provide examples of the code you are using so far

Comment: can't post code - this thing says it's spam... ARRRrrrrr!!!

Answer (score 0):

hmmm - well - I was overflowing a pipe, which seems to be what was causing the hang ... but the empty stream on the backbenimble page still a problem...